# Displaying output of file from a dropdown menu selection

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, echo

First off, I am totally new to PHP, but so far i love the possibilities i have seen with it.

Ok, heres my problem. I have a script that will automatically scan a folder and show me the file names of that folder in a drop-down menu.

```
<?php
$dirname = "logs";
$dir = opendir($dirname);
echo '<select name="file2">';
echo '<option value="">Logfiles</option>';
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
        {
            if(($file != ".") and ($file != ".."))
                {
        echo "<option value=".$file.">$file</option>";
                }
        }
                echo '</select>';
?>
```

So far so good, that part works just fine.

I then have a piece of code that would show me the contents of a chosen file.

```
<?php
$content = file("filenamehere");
$data = implode("<br>",$content);
echo $data;
?>
```

This part on its own also works fine.

I now want to combine these 2 scripts. This is where i get totally lost. I have tried all various combinations of which variable to put as a "filenamehere", but I only get as far as having my choice from the drop-down echoing the chosen filename in the drop-down button. I have not been able to actually get the 2nd part of the code to display the file contents of the file I have chosen. I tried things like ("$file") for the $content variable but nothing happens.

Of course any other single script solution would also be great. I just need to be able to scan a folder, have its files listed in a drop-down, and once i choose a file i want it to be displayed on the page.

Any help would be deeply appreciated since im a total beginner in PHP.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am assuming you are doing everything in a single page. I have wrapped a `form` tag around the `select` dropdown and added a submit button

```
echo '<form name="displayfile" action="" method="POST">';
echo '<select name="file2">';
echo '<option value="">Logfiles</option>';
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
        {
            if(($file != ".") and ($file != ".."))
                {
        echo "<option value=".$file.">$file</option>";
                }
        }
                echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="display file" />';
echo '</form>';
```

The second part

```
<?php
    //file2 is the name of the dropdown
    $selectedfile = @$_POST['file2'];
    $content = file($selectedfile);
    $data = implode("<br>",$content);
    echo $data;

?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Brilliant, I just had to edit the path in your second part for the $content, and it works perfectly. Thank you ever so much :)

Comment: May i request your help one more time. If i would like to add a download button that would download the selected file, how could i implement that to use the file name based on the drop-down selection?

Comment: add another button: `<input type="button onclick="document.forms['displayfile'].action='download.php';document.forms['displayfile'].submit();" value="download this file" />`. Then create the download.php

Comment: You can search StackOverflow for how to do download in PHP and put the script in your download.php. Check http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-file-download, http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm, http://www.vijayjoshi.org/2008/11/25/how-to-allow-users-to-download-files-in-php/

Comment: yes, i alread have a download.php in place and ready. I just didn't know how to link the new button to it. I tried the button code you posted but i get an error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /log.php on line 150` @tcoder

Comment: try this `echo '<input type="button" onclick="document.forms[\'displayfile\'].action=\'download.php\';document.forms[\'dis‌​playfile\'].submit();" value="download this file" />';`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very very much :) You've been a great help for my little project.